# Using Through function with vectors

Tags: vector, options, operators

I have the vectors defined as follows:

```
v1={x1,y1,z1};
v2={x2,y2,z2};
v12=v2-v1;
v21=v1-v2;
```

I am passing an integer function for iteration purpose as follows:

```
Through[v1[i]]
```

and it gives me a correct answer,

```
 {x1[i],y1[i],z1[i]}
```

However when I try the following function setup,

```
 Through[v12[i]]
```

I am getting a wrong answer,

```
  {(-x1+x2)[i],(-y1+y2)[i],(-z1+z2)[i]}
```

my answer should be,

```
 {-x1[i]+x2[i],-y1[i]+y2[i],-z1[i]+z2[i]}
```

How do I fix this?  Looks like I have to go Through twice but I have no clue how to this.

Comment: Why couldn't you do `Through[v2[i]] - Through[v1[i]]` instead?

Comment: This is because, if you look at `v2`, you will see it is already changed to `{-x1+x2,-y1+y2,-z1+z2}`

Comment: @J.M., Yes I did that already but I wondered if there is some alternative and more compact trick in solving this problem.

Answer (score 4):

I think it's going to be hairy to do the Through after the arithmetic. Try this instead:

```
Through[v2[i]] - Through[v1[i]]
```

(oops, J.M. got there first)

Comment: You posted an answer, and answers trump comments, always. ;D